# How do I retrieve data from HTML?

Tags: java, html, parsing, web-scraping

I'm writing an android app that requires me to download the `html` code from a website and retrieve data that I need and discard the rest. Also I might need to convert the code into `xml` or `json` format.

Comment: Can explore [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library.

Comment: Jsoup, HtmlUnit, Selenium ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i don't know if this is exactly what you wanted or how this works as i am not a android expert hope this helps anyway
Regards
Tom

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/android-xml-adventure-parsing-html-using-jsoup/